# Discussion-Like answers on a old question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-delete

In the review queue I found [this *Q/A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870/arrays-of-arrays-in-java) which to me seems more like a discussion.

My intuition would say, most of the *lower answers* (those that start with an @[username]) would qualify for being an answer to another question or a too-long-a-comment, not striving anymore to answer the question as it was originally stated by the OP.

However it strikes me, that this question is already from 2008.

In my opinion, someone should have stepped in, when the *thread* was created, to make the people create multiple, distinct and concise questions and answers, instead of putting everything in one discussion-like thread of answers.

For now, I am unsure what to recommend. I mean - it is ancient, it might contain useful information (that I can't judge) to people that stumble upon that question. But it is hard to find the right information as it obfuscated in that discussion.

What is the right call here:

Recommend deletion - or - keep?

---

Has there maybe been a rule change in the last 9 years, and that style was alright before?

Comment: All 4 of the @ answers should be deleted. How old something is does not affect whether or not we delete something (unless it has 1000's of votes, in which case locking could be a better option).

Comment: At that time, the concept of comments wasn't there. IIRC.

Comment: @Dukeling You don't lock something because it's got thousands of votes, you lock something because it's *of overwhelmingly high value and it would be detrimental to the site to have it not be there anymore*.  There are plenty of old posts without thousands of upvotes that aren't actually useful, and have thus been deleted, and also posts that don't have such a massive score that have still been determined to be worthwhile enough to lock instead of deleting.

Comment: Or better yet, look for a site (aka not here) where those things are welcomed and can be actively maintained. As this very post demonstrates, we are quite bad at maintaining stuff.